# IRC "proxy" for persistent connection between several computers

Tags: irc

I'm looking for a program that enables me to stay connected to one or more IRC networks and be able to view the log even though I connect from several different computers.

I'm thinking about something like a proxy running on a server who always is connected to the servers/channels I want and to which I connect from whichever client I want to use.

Does anyone know of a program like this?

Edit: Apparently I could be running a IRC session in a shell on a server and connect to this but I would like something more GUI:ish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ZNC](http://wiki.znc.in/ZNC) should work just fine.

After initial setup it can be configured through a web interface or by communicating with it through IRC messages.
When using the same account from multiple clients, I found it helpful to load the [route_replies](http://wiki.znc.in/Route_replies) module.

[image: ZNC Web Interface]

Answer (score 4):

The general term for software that does this is "IRC bouncer" and it wasn't too uncommon in the days of dialup.  Many in the early days of the Internet would dial-in to a Unix host (possibly the one providing dialup Internet service to you) and run the bouncer there, and then if your unreliable dial-up connection dropped, your connection to the IRC network would remain uninterrupted.  Very important in the days before NickServ/ChanServ and all that to try to prevent channels from being taken over.

Definitely recommend ZNC as @Oliver Salzburg says over another common one called "PsyBNC."